# A good way to "centralize" instances provided by a library?

Tags: java

I have written [this project](https://github.com/fge/msg-simple) and already use it in other libraries of mine.

However, I find something amiss. Namely, in each user of this library, I create a utility class whose only role is to provide one or more `MessageBundle`s. And this sucks.

I'd like to have, built into the library, a mechanism in order to have library users be able to register/recall bundles.

My first idea would be to have a singleton factory with a `.register()` and `.get()` method (with appropriate checks for duplicate keys etc) and call these from within `static` initialization blocks...

... But there is a problem: there is no guarantee as to which static initialization block will be called first.

Knowing that I'd like to keep the dependencies of this library "intact" (which is to mean, no external dependency at all), what solution would you recommend?

(note: this is Java 6+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the standard support for service providers: [ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html). You would simply require each user of your library to provide an implementation of some interface, for example

```
public interface MessageBundleProvider {
    List<MessageBundle> getBundles();
}
```

The name of the class implementing this interface would have to be specified in a file of the jar file of the user library named `META-INF/services/com.example.MessageBundleProvider`.

At runtime, your library would automatically discover all the message bundle providers using the following code:

```
private static final ServiceLoader<MessageBundleProvider> LOADER
    = ServiceLoader.load(MessageBundleProvider.class);

private static final List<MessageBundle> BUNDLES;

static { 
    BUNDLES = new ArrayList<MessageBundle>();
    for (MessageBundleProvider provider : loader) {
         for (MessageBundle bundle : provider.getBundles()) {
             BUNDLES.add(bundle);
         }
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I know that ServiceLoader exists, but I've never used it before. It's how all the standard Java service providers are discovered, though (like JDBC drivers, charset providers, etc.).

Comment: Hmm, I know of this mechanism, however it has a problem: if more than one library is used which uses a same service loader, as far as I know, the services file entries will not be merged :/

Comment: Yes, they will. When you have multiple JDBC drivers, each in their own jar, and each providing their own Driver class, all the drivers are registereed with the DriverManager. Same here. The service loader is in your MessageBundle library. The users of the library must only provide the MessageBundleProvider implementation, declared in the META-INF folder of their jar.

Comment: Ah, OK... Maybe this is due to the fact that I had to deal with building a project actually having to produce services, and each module had its own service file! So, this looks like a solution, except for the fact that it requires projects to generate that manifest... I'll investigate some more.

Comment: You could also simply document the fact that bundles must be registered before the central utility class can return them. Just like before the service provider existed, you had to do Class.forName("the.jdbc.Driver") to have the driver register itself to the DriverManager. It's up to the client to use the library correctly.

Comment: Yup, the more I think about it, the more appealing this solution seems to be. I have had another design in mind which had the interface requirements but not the manifest generation... On the other hand it led to the possibility of conflicts. I guess the hardest part for me here is to give Maven instructions as to how to generate that manifest! Maven and I are really not friendly to one another :(

Comment: I can only sympathize. I hate Maven. Consider using Gradle: much better designed.

Comment: Well, I have thought about using gradle for some time already... What has always pulled me back is the fact that it is not as widely deployed as Maven is :/

Comment: Then you'll be a precursor :) Note that this should be transparent to the users of your library: Gradle can generate pom files and deploy to a Maven repo without problem. And Gradle will quickly be used on a large scale: Android has chosen it as the official build tool in its SDK, that all Android developers use.

Comment: Tested, and working! There's even a Maven plugin for it: https://github.com/francisdb/serviceloader-maven-plugin. Thanks!